# ビルドができません。

Tags: monaca

初めてmonacaを触ってみて、実機ビルドしようとしたのですが、

[ドキュメントの手順](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/manual/build/ios/build_ios/)どおりにやっても上手くいかず...

同じようなエラーが出て解決された方がいたらご教授願いたいです。

[image]